# Find same file name in different folders, and utilize two files for a certain task in python

Tags: python

There are folders in different folders like below

```
folder 1 - a, b, c...
folder 2 - a, b, c ...
```

And each folder has files with similar names like below

```
folder 1 - a - one.csv, two.csv,...
folder 2 - a - one_pred.csv, two_pred.csv,...
```

I would like to check files in each folder and when it finds same folder, go into the folder and when it finds `one.csv & one_pred.csv` for instance,

It goes to the ML performance check function

```
rms = get_rms(one, one_pred)
```

But I'm not sure how to loop through two different folder at the same time and pass them to the function.

I tried

```
folders = os.listdir(folder1)
for d in folders:
    files = os.listdir(folder1 + d)
    for f in files:
        if f.split('_')[-1] == 'pred':
            f_truth = f.replace('_pred','')
            rms = get_rms(f_truth, f)
```

It didn't work. I thought this was wrong before I ran it, but I had no idea what I should do differently...

Comment: Can you use the tree method of representation of the directory structure I cannot quite understand, also are there only 2 folders or there are more than that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python's `os.walk()` to get a list of files in both folders. Then match them as per your needs and run whichever function you want on them.
Use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) reference to understand how to use `os.walk()`.